# Loadrunner Controller Goal Scenario configuration

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have script which must run for 2 Hour, and  make 4 Requests per Second in the first 15 minutes, and for 1 minute the requests must be increased to 10 Requests per Second and then back for 4 Requests per second for the next 15 minutes, and so on . that means the requests are increased for  6 requests only for minute after every 15 minutes and of course all that for 2 Hour.
I don't know to achieve that, what is better goal-oriented or manual scenario

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, you probably want to use Jmeter instead of Loadrunner. Jmeter allows much better granular use of raw requests. Whereas Loadrunner is more focussed around 'users' which is probably not what you're after. You may struggle reaching your specific throughput targets.

Anyway, to make this scenario in Loadrunner, create a new scenario with 'Real-world schedule, by test'.
Then in the bottom left, enter in the scenario details: (Click the new button to add a new row)

- Initialise all Vusers simultaneously
- Start 4 vusers simultaneously
- Run for 15 minutes
- Start 6 users simultaneously
- Run for 1 minute
- Stop 6 users simultaneously
- Run for 14 minutes
- and so on....

Comment: "Jmeter allows much better granular use of raw requests."   See LoadRunner Winsock or custom agent with Visual Studio or Nix Compiler.   Simultaneity does not happen with a human population - this requires synchronization to a clock tick.  See book "Chaos,  Making  a New Science" by James Gleick for insight into the behavior of natural populations and what this means for performance testing

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this tool for two decades.  That is the most convoluted non business related requirement I have ever read.  I have no idea how you configure any performance testing tool to accomplish your task because you will have to make so many assumptions about the nature of the request, how long it takes to complete, think time, etc... to get anywhere near a defined rate.   Plus, make just a couple of changes to a server involving cache management and the number of requests could drop by 75-80% for the same number of users.   This appears to have been written by a server administrator and not a business owner.

Ask for the HTTP request logs from production for analysis.

Comment: @Pulley..we want to check the behavior of the server during the 1 minute peak load test, because we have problem only if the requests get increased.

Comment: @Pulley...please in the future either you give short answers  or stay away and spare us you long story about laodrunner which is not useful at all